# FullCalendar React: Can I document.getElementByClassName once the calendar has rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm really struggling to figure out how access the DOM elements after the calendar is loaded... I've tried various ways to incorporate useEffect, I've tried using Refs, including the fullCalendarRef as well as creating my own ref, but to no avail.

As we know, when `<FullCalendar>` renders/is created, it generates various divs, including for example, a `<div class="fc-view-harness">`.

I want to attach an event listener to this element, but I have no way of accessing it (or at least I don't know how to organize the code such that I can access the element)

At a high level my code is organized as:

```jsx
const MyCalendar(()=>{
     
     useEffect(()=>{
        //insert some stuff here
     },[])

     const onClickDate = ()=>{ 
     //and other handler functions like this
     }

     return(
        <VariousDivsAndContainers>
           <FullCalendar
              plugins={[
                    dayGridPlugin,
                    listPlugin,
                    timeGridPlugin,
                    resourceTimeGridPlugin,
                    interactionPlugin,
                  ]}
              dateClick={(info) => {
                    onClickDate(info);
                  }}
              otherProps={fakeValue}
            />
        </VariousDivsAndContainers>
     )

})
```

Can I make what I'm seeking with getElementByClassName or useRef, and if so how?

Ultimately I want to add a 'wheel' event listener so that I can see if someone is pinch zooming (since browsers recognize such a gesture as a wheel event with a ctrlKey)

Again, I tried doing this in the useEffect. I tried putting it outside the MyCalendar component. I tried wrapping the `<FullCalendar` with another div ref. I tried doing it through the interactive callBack (like "onClickDate". Except I want it active not just on that action, but when the loading of the calendar finishes)

Answer (score 1):

Provided that...

1. `FullCalendar` does not already offer the event you're interested in as a callback, and
2. It doesn't already capture the event and stop propagation

You can wrap the component in your own element, attach a ref and add your own delegated event listener.

For example

```jsx
const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => {
    const viewHarness = e.target.closest(".fc-view-harness");
    if (viewHarness) {
      // the event occurred within the .fc-view-harness element
    }
  });

  const wrapper = wrapperRef.current;
  wrapper?.addEventListener("wheel", handler);

  // remove the listener on cleanup
  return () => {
    wrapper?.removeEventListener("wheel", handler);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <div ref={wrapperRef}>
    <FullCalendar ... />
  </div>
);
```